How does the daguerrotype give directly a positive image?
I have read the wikipedia entry about the old photographic process called
daguerrotype.
It says there

The image is on a mirror-like silver surface and will appear either positive or negative, depending on the angle at which it is viewed, how it is lit and whether a light or dark background is being reflected in the metal. The darkest areas of the image are simply bare silver;

As I understand it, to make a daguerrotype one first exposes a the silver coating of a copper plate to iodine fumes. This creates a layer of silver iodide which is white, and light-sensitive. When exposed to light the silver iodide is affected, but this is not directly visible. To get an image some more chemical reaction is needed.
In "modern" BW photography (that is, the one used for a long time before color photography and of course before digital) the silver iodide that was exposed (light part of the initial image) was reduced to metallic silver that appeared dark, while there was no silver in the part of the image that was not exposed to light (dark part of the of the initial image) which remained clear. Thus a negative image was obtained and had to be reversed by a second exposition to light.
But daguerrotype does not have a second exposition. Anyway, it is not transparent because of the copper plate. It is directly positive. Granted, wikipedia says it can be negative "depending... ". But mainly it is positive as is obvious when one looks at old daguerrotypes, for instance the two that illustrate the wiki page I mention above. And the wikipedia does say "the darkest areas... are pure silver", meaning those that were not exposed to light, in a "positive" image.
The chemical process involves mercury fumes. I would like to understand how this works to create an image which is directly positive at least for the more usual way that

it is lit and whether a light or dark background is being reflected in the metal


It depends on the angle of incidence of the light.
If the light is near the eye, and the rays are perpendicular to the surface, then the smoother silver reflects more light back to the eye, and one sees a negative image.
If the light falls at an angle on the roughened areas, and the polished silver is aimed to reflect a black surface towards the eye, then the image appears positive.
As Wikipedia states, "The darkest areas of the image are simply bare silver; lighter areas have a microscopically fine light-scattering texture."
As stated in Photo StackExchange, "The highly-exposed areas, what we would normally think of as "lighter", are rendered more diffuse through added fine texture, making them somewhat more like paper - the brightness changes in a fairly predictable way depending on the overall lighting. The less exposed areas, however, retain a more mirror-like finish." I.E.,Unexposed areas are smooth silver; mercury has reacted with salts in the exposed areas to produce texture.
The eye perceives "black" and "white" by contrast with surroundings. In the image below, from the American Museum of Natural History, the shade of the bar varies by the background. The same is true for a Daguerreotype.

Note:
Heating mercury in the studio was not conducive to health. Charles Lutwidge Dodgson was an avid photographer -- perhaps his Mad Hatter should have been a Mad Photographer?

The smooth silver should be where a lot of light have reached the plate, so what should be white in a positive image. So the positive image should be with rays perpendicular to the surface. Did you mean what you wrote or did you mistakenly interchange positive and negative ? It would make senses in that case. Please confirm, since I cannot accept your answer as it stands.

@Alfred, As Wikipedia states, "The darkest areas of the image are simply bare silver; lighter areas have a microscopically fine light-scattering texture."

How come the dark part, where the iodide was not affected by light, are bare silver, while light parts, which were affected by light, have kept their iodide ? This was the chemical question I asked from the beginning. What is the exact role of the mercury fumes ?

Before I accept your answer, please explain more clearly the chemistry of all that. Does the mercury fix the exposed salts ? ? What is the chemical reaction ? Form an amalgam the silver only on the exposed parts? And the amalgam stays on the plate ? While the non-exposed are washed away ? That is my initial question and I still do not consider the answer as sufficiently explicit.

Re : Mercury fumes. I had the same reaction. Daguerrotypists were certainly exposed to mercury. They probably did have a lot of medical problems.. "Mad Hatter/ Mad Daguerrotypists" did come to my mind !

I upvoted your answer as useful but I am not ready to accept it without a detailed description of the effect of the mercury fumes.

I have read DrMoishe Pippik's answer to my question, and also various other pages on daguerrotypes.
What I have learned from all these documents, and a lot from DrMoishe Pippik's answer is that though in a different lighting the daguerrotype can appear as a negative image, the way the light on daguerrotype is usually oriented the image appears positive.
The way it happens is that areas that were not exposed to light are pure silver and reflect the lighting away from the eye of the observer, and so appear black. Areas that received a lot of light appear white, or at least a shade of gray that is interpreted by the eye as white compared to the "black" pure silver.
All this I learned recently. But it still does not answer my initial question on the chemical reaction that led to this situation.
So I will now provisionally try to answer my own question using the above information.
A thin layer of silver iodide was formed on the silver-covered copper plate. Silver iodide is light-sensitive.
I now assume that silver iodide untouched by light is not affected by the mercury vapor. So if rinsed with some chemical solvent, or maybe just water, it dissolves away and leaves a clean silver surface (that acts as a mirror and sends light away from the observer's eye in lighting meant for positive image).
Contrariwise silver iodide crystals that have received light have been "weakened" and mercury vapors can attack these crystals, extract silver atoms and form an amalgam. The "micro texture" of these small amalgam droplets stick on the silver and are not washed away. So the more light reaches an area, the more amalgam droplets are formed. Though these droplets are probably rather dark, they do diffuse light in all directions including towards the eye of the observer. So by contrast with the total absence of light towards the eye of the observer coming from the mirror-like pure silver, these amalgam droplets make the areas where they are look lighter, and all the lighter that the droplets are more numerous, that is, the original projected image was luminous, so more silver iodide crystals were illuminated and thus able to allow mercury to attack the silver atoms in the salt.
This is how I understand what happens
But I am not going to accept my own answer now.
I hope someone can either confirm this answer, or explain to me where I erred, since I am not fully sure of what I just wrote.

EDIT
I have asked the same question on another StackExchange Community, namely History  of Science and Mathematics.
There I did get an answer by BowlOfRed. He wrote

The iodine (or later iodine and bromine) turn the plate yellow.


The photoactivated silver more readily reacts with the mercury. The silver mercury amalgam that is formed is described as milky white.


I believe the halide is then removed by the hypo fixing process. The silver that remains is highly reflective. If untarnished, it is a good mirror rather than being white or black.

All this fits with my provisional answer here. I have of course accepted his answer there.
